# fabric sudo permission denied

Tags: python, sudo, fabric

setup:

- fabric 1.9.1
- server is centOS 7
- user tester0 has admin privileges & is in sudoers file

Issue: When I'm trying to create folder under '/opt/' it returns "Permission denied".

From my fabfile.py:

```
parent_code_dir = '/opt/deploy_dest'
with settings(sudo_user=pt_root_user,warn_only=False):
     sudo("ls /opt/") #this works OK with the sudo command
     sudo("id") #this works OK with the sudo command
     sudo("mkdir -p %s" % parent_code_dir) #this returns the "Permission denied"
```

In my terminal I see the output:

```
[192.168.1.108] sudo: ls
[192.168.1.108] out: rh
[192.168.1.108] out: 

[192.168.1.108] sudo: id
[192.168.1.108] out: uid=1000(tester0) gid=1000(tester0) groups=1000(tester0),10(wheel)   context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[192.168.1.108] out: 

[192.168.1.108] sudo: mkdir -p /opt/deploy_dest/
[192.168.1.108] out: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/opt/deploy_dest/’: Permission denied
Fatal error: sudo() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
Requested: mkdir -p /opt/pt_server/
Executed: sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "tester0"  /bin/bash -l -c "mkdir -p /opt/pt_server/"
```

I was able to create the same folder manually `sudo mkdir -p /opt/deploy_dest` over ssh when accessing as tester0.
Yet when I run the output `sudo -S -p 'sudo password:'  -u "tester0"  /bin/bash -l -c "mkdir -p /opt/pt_server/"` I get the same error so I guess I should change the fabric sudo_prefix..

Is there a better solution? have I missed somthing?

Answer (score 2):

It was a matter of permissions in the /opt/ folder. 
the user tester0 isn't root => he is in the group wheel which has root permissions but when running 
sudo -u => as the tester0 user accessing /opt/ which he only in the group but the group doesn't allow write. 
One fast solution is  `chmod g+w /opt/`